# How to use a method with an array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

So I've pretty much accomplished everything I've needed to for my little program save the last item. I need to create a method that will take the average of the two games worth of data and print it out to display at the end.
Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Final
{
class FinalProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Declaring Arrays for the players, games/avg, and stats.
        double[, ,] stats = new double[3, 2, 10];
        string[] players = new string[3];
        int x, y;

        //Here is my Pre-set Array
        players[0] = "Tom Brady";
        players[1] = "Drew Brees";
        players[2] = "Peyton Manning";
        //Here starts my loops that will ask for first players stats for game 1 first,        then loop to game 2. After that finishes it will loop to player 2, etc.
        for (x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter stats for {0}", players[x]);
            for (y = 0; y < 2; ++y)
            {
                //Here starts my writeable array. This was to save from having to ask the question about stats 60 times in code.
                Console.WriteLine("Game {0}", y + 1);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter pass attempts: ");
                stats[x, y, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                /*Console.WriteLine("Enter completions: ");    (Just saving from having to enter a ton of data while testing)
                stats[x, y, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter completion percentage: ");
                stats[x, y, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter total yards: ");
                stats[x, y, 3] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter touchdowns: ");
                stats[x, y, 4] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter interceptions: ");
                stats[x, y, 5] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter rushing yards: ");
                stats[x, y, 6] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter rushing touchdowns: ");
                stats[x, y, 7] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter fumbles: ");
                stats[x, y, 8] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter QB rating: ");
                stats[x, y, 9] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());*/
            }
        }

        char letter = 'a';
        string input;
        {
            while (letter != 'z' || letter != 'Z')
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the first letter of the first name of a player (T, D, P), enter A for all players, or Z to quit: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                letter = Convert.ToChar(input);
                if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'A')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player             Att   Comp  Comp %  PYards PTD INT RYards  RTD  F  QBR");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}  - Avg  - {1}    {2}     {3}      {4}    {5}   {6}   {7}     {8}   {9}  {10}", players[0], stats[0, 1, 0], stats[0, 1, 1], stats[0, 1, 2].ToString("P"), stats[0, 1, 3], stats[0, 1, 4], stats[0, 1, 5], stats[0, 1, 6], stats[0, 1, 7], stats[0, 1, 8], stats[0, 1, 9].ToString("P"));
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}  - Avg  - {1}    {2}     {3}      {4}    {5}   {6}   {7}     {8}   {9}  {10}", players[1], stats[1, 1, 0], stats[1, 1, 1], stats[1, 1, 2].ToString("P"), stats[1, 1, 3], stats[1, 1, 4], stats[1, 1, 5], stats[1, 1, 6], stats[1, 1, 7], stats[1, 1, 8], stats[1, 1, 9].ToString("P"));
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}- Avg- {1}    {2}     {3}      {4}    {5}   {6}   {7}     {8}   {9}  {10}", players[2], stats[2, 1, 0], stats[2, 1, 1], stats[2, 1, 2].ToString("P"), stats[2, 1, 3], stats[2, 1, 4], stats[2, 1, 5], stats[2, 1, 6], stats[2, 1, 7], stats[2, 1, 8], stats[2, 1, 9].ToString("P"));
                }
                else if (letter == 't' || letter == 'T')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player             Att   Comp  Comp %  PYards PTD INT RYards  RTD  F  QBR");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}  - Avg  - {1}    {2}     {3}      {4}    {5}   {6}   {7}     {8}   {9}  {10}", players[0], stats[0, 1, 0], stats[0, 1, 1], stats[0, 1, 2].ToString("P"), stats[0, 1, 3], stats[0, 1, 4], stats[0, 1, 5], stats[0, 1, 6], stats[0, 1, 7], stats[0, 1, 8], stats[0, 1, 9].ToString("P"));
                }
                else if (letter == 'd' || letter == 'D')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player             Att   Comp  Comp %  PYards PTD INT RYards  RTD  F  QBR");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}  - Avg  - {1}    {2}     {3}      {4}    {5}   {6}   {7}     {8}   {9}  {10}", players[1], stats[1, 1, 0], stats[1, 1, 1], stats[1, 1, 2].ToString("P"), stats[1, 1, 3], stats[1, 1, 4], stats[1, 1, 5], stats[1, 1, 6], stats[1, 1, 7], stats[1, 1, 8], stats[1, 1, 9].ToString("P"));
                }
                else if (letter == 'p' || letter == 'P')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Player             Att   Comp  Comp %  PYards PTD INT RYards  RTD  F  QBR");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}- Avg- {1}    {2}     {3}      {4}    {5}   {6}   {7}     {8}   {9}  {10}", players[2], stats[2, 1, 0], stats[2, 1, 1], stats[2, 1, 2].ToString("P"), stats[2, 1, 3], stats[2, 1, 4], stats[2, 1, 5], stats[2, 1, 6], stats[2, 1, 7], stats[2, 1, 8], stats[2, 1, 9].ToString("P"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, not a valid initial.");
                    Console.Write("Enter next players initial or Z to quit ");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                    letter = Convert.ToChar(input);
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

So basically I have it set right now to just print out the stats that were entered for each player. I need to change the printed stat from displaying a "game" to displaying the average of the two "games" that were entered, and am not real sure how to do that.

If anyone can help or at least push me in the right direction, I would be truly appreciative. I also wanted to mention that I'm a very beginner coder, so I'm not looking to condense or do anything crazy with what I have, just add that last function in. I need to use a method to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: I have my comment lines in place for description in most areas. I have it commented out the large group in my for loop so I can test easily without having to put ALL of the data in

Comment: TL;DR; - based on length of sample http://codereview.stackexchange.com is probably better place.

Comment: Please check out http://sscce.org/ - there is huge negative value in posting whole lot of randomly commented out code...

Comment: I also went to codereview.stackexchange.com, thank you for pointing me in the right direction as I asked!

Answer (score 0):

```
public double[,] GetAveragesOfThirdDimension(double[,,] input)
{
    double[,] averages = new double[input.GetLength(0), input.GetLength(1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < input.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < input.GetLength(2); k++)
            {
                averages[i,j] = averages[i,j] + input[i,j,k];
            }
            averages[i,j] = averages[i,j] / input.GetLength(2);
        }
    }
    return averages;
}
```